# What are the design patterns and supporting technologies for sharing complex objects between microservices?

Tags: microservices

**Question: Given that two services operate on a common complex object, what are possible design patterns and supporting technologies of exchanging the object and (possibly) sharing the implementation?**

How about aspects like

- deployment (independent release cycles on the two services)
- testing (using different implementation makes testing much harder)?

*If you name a possible solution, please give reference. If possible also name design patterns and technologies enabling the solution.*

**Sample Use Case**

The question may require a small introduction (*tl;dr warning*), apologies for this. In the following, I construct some “use case” related to “fitting” (microservice 1) and “using” (mircoservice 2) a “curve” (complex object). This is just to illustrate the question.

By a “curve” I consider an object representing a function t -> value(t) mapping floating point numbers to floating point numbers. Such a curve can be constructed, for example, from a set of sample points *(t_i, v_i)* and the specification of an (possibly complex) interpolation method. However there may be also other *implementations* like parametric curves.

For such a curve we may have an interface, e.g.

```
public interface Curve {
   double getValue(double time);
}
```

and an implementation

The implementation may provide different interpolations methods.

Now consider two “services” (or say modules, to get rid of the word “service”) which perform some actions on a “curve”.

**The first service** performs a fitting (or calibration), that is, given

- times t_{i}
- constraints F_j( curve ) -> min (j=1,…,m)
- specification of an interpolation method or parametrization

it determines the best fitting values v_{i} to minimize the constraints F_{j}

The service then provides the fitted curve(s) which are described by a POJO. For example, for interpolating curves

```
Double[] times; // t_{i}
Double[] value; // v_{i}
String interpolationMethod; // interpolation method
```

or for parametric curves

```
Double[] value; // v_{i}
String parametrizationMethod; // specification of the function used
```

Note that the result of this fitting – of course – depends on the specific interpolation method or parametrization used for the curve. (A best fit linear interpolation is different from a best fit spline interpolation).

**The second service** (or in general *other services*) uses given curves (POJOs) and provides some derived quantities (for example an integral). You may pass a curve to this service it calculates something for you, for example some function G(curve).

This requires that we need to pass the curve to the second service, e.g. represented by our POJO.

Note also that the result of this valuation depends on the specific interpolation method used for the curve.

**Both services agree on a common specification**

In order to get consistent results, the two services have to agree on a defined specification of “the curve”. This is a specification of how the result object of the first service has to be interpreted and of how the input object of the second service has to be interpreted.
*In other words, this is the specification of how the POJO is used to implement the Curve interface.*

If the first services allows for a new or modified version of the interpolation method, this has to be part of a new specification (some versioning of the interpolation method (like SPLINE_V1 or SPLINE_V2).

**Sharing a common implementation - or not?**

In my view, it is an advantage to provide a common implementation of the Curve interface to both services. This would imply that “errors” in the implementation exists on both side, which is sometimes an advantage in terms of consistency (I can explain this in more detail, if required).

Also, having two independent implementations also feels like a violation of [DRY](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself).

On the other hand, the philosophy of a microservice suggests to keep both services completely (?) independent, possibly suggesting to use independent implementations (versions?) of the complex object (e.g. service 1 provides curves “up to” SPLINE_V2, but service 2 can operate only on curves “up to” SPLINE_V1).

(Sorry for the tl;dr ).

*Remark:* The motivation for the use of a microservice in the first place is that the Curve object is used by different other components/clients/etc. and the fitting - as a time consuming process - should be cached or centralized.

*Remark:* The question may already arise on much simpler component, like a common method for de-serialization and serialization of some shared data structures.

*Related questions and topics:*

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961000/why-shared-libraries-between-microservices-are-bad
  Note: While I do understand that a shared library introduces a coupling and I do understand that coupling is undesired (or bad), the situation here is different, because the implementation is related to the object being transferred between the two services.
- [How do you handle shared concepts in a microservice architecture?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277011/how-do-you-handle-shared-concepts-in-a-microservice-architecture)

Comment: I modified the question and explicitly asking for references (like the ones at the bottom) and technologies to reduce opinionated answers.

Comment: I would argue that separating code into "services" like this is not really advantageous. Given your example, I just don't see any advantage given the complications separating the two.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a solution that doesnt use 'microservices'? The use case you describe is quite abstract, but i can see nothing here that warrants the overhead of having isolated services

Comment: A motivation for a microservice would be that the fitted curve is maybe used by different other parts differently. (I have added a remark to motivate this better).